# References about Nemytskii Mappings

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, calculus-of-variations

I need some references about Nemytskii Mappings. Can anyone tell me some textbook about it?

I am reading chapter 2 of this text [www.math.tifr.res.in/~publ/ln/tifr81.pdf](http://www.math.tifr.res.in/~publ/ln/tifr81.pdf) . And I need more results about Nemytskii.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-1-4419-6950-7_6

Comment: The book "A primer in nonlinear analysis" by Prodi and Ambrosetti covers this topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a book about it. In this book, the authors call Nemytskii operators as superposition operators.

http://www.cambridge.org/us/academic/subjects/mathematics/abstract-analysis/nonlinear-superposition-operators#contentsTabAnchor